# jQuery not working on added rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table to allow user to do multiple stock entry

```
<table class="table1" id="table1">
  <thread>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Item Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Qty</th>
      <th scope="col">Rate</th>
      <th scope="col">Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thread>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td><input type="text"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" class="num" id="qty"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" class="num" id="rate"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" class="num" id="amt"/></td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<a id="add"><button>Add</button></a>
```

And this code is to add a new row:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#add").click(function() {
      var newrow = $("<tr><td><input type="text"/></td><td><input type=\"text\" id=\"qty\"/></td><td><input type="\text\" id="\rate\"/></td><td><input type="\text\" id="\amt\"/></td></tr>");
    newrow.insertAfter('#table1 tbody>tr:last');
    return false;
  });
  $(".num").keyup(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if (id == 'qty') {
      var i = parseFloat($("#rate").val())
      if (!isNaN(i)) {
        var t = ($(this).val()*$("#rate").val());
        $("#amt").val(t.toFixed(2));
      } else {
        $("#amt").val('');
      }
    } else if (id == 'rate') {
      var i = parseFloat($("#qty").val())
      if (!isNaN(i)) {
        var t = ($(this).val()*$("#qty").val());
        $("#amt").val(t.toFixed(2));
      } else {
        $("#amt").val('');
      }
    }
  });
});
```

The calculation is working perfect on the first row of table, but when I am adding a second row the calculation is not working. Where I am wrong?

Comment: let me guess , it keeps calculating only the first row?

Comment: If you do like that, you will have multiple `td` with the same id, thats not proper html. Try to use classes instead of id's. Ex: `class="qty"` instead of `id="qty"`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use event delegation:

```
$('body').on('keyup', ".num", function() {
    // your code
});
```

Also you must add class `.num` to your created elements, 
and you can't have the same ID for multiple elements, instead
use another attribute (like `data-id`, it doesn't matter),

```
var newrow = $('<tr><td><input type="text" /></td><td><input type="text" class="num" data-id="qty"/></td><td><input type="text" data-id="rate"/></td><td><input type="text" class="num" data-id="amt" /></td></tr>');
```

And in your function get them with this attribute:

```
$('body').on('keyup', ".num", function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var $amt = $row.find('[data-id="amt"]');
    var $qty = $row.find('[data-id="qty"]');
    var $rate = $row.find('[data-id="rate"]');

    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');

    if (id == 'qty') {
        // now using `$rate` instead of $('#rate')
        var i = parseFloat($rate.val())

        // other code
    }

    // other code
});
```

Comment: I have tried it but it is not firing on keyup event

Comment: @MandeepSingh Which version of jQuery you are running? It must be at least `1.7`.

Comment: pls help how to update jquery version in xampp

Answer (score 1):

Give the new rows the `num` class (your new inputs don't have it), and use `.on`:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.num', function() {

});
```

This is required if you want to add an event listener to elements that are not yet in the DOM.

Also, element IDs should be unique. Your new inputs are getting the same ID as the previous row.

Comment: you mean in jquery i have to give the new id on each time add is clicked?

Comment: No, I would remove the IDs, you shouldn't need them. Just use the classes.

Answer (score 1):

This issue can be solved via event delegation to the existing closet parent like in your case is  `$('#table1')` or `$(document)` which is the parent of all the elements on a page, so you need to change this:

```
$(".num").keyup(function() {
```

to this:

```
$("#table").on('keyup', '.num', function() {
```

---

I just seen your additions you are adding same ids when clicked to add, so that results in a invalid html markup due to ids should be unique in the same page (*`same ids for multiple elems is invalid`*).

```
 var newrow = $("<tr><td><input type='text'/></td>"+
                "<td><input type='text' id='qty'/></td>"+
                "<td><input type='text' id='rate'/></td>"+
                "<td><input type='text' id='amt'/></td></tr>");
```

The above one everytime adds same id for multiple elements when added to the dom. you can try to do this way:

```
  $("#add").click(function () {
    var i = $("#table1 tbody>tr:last").index();
    var newrow = $("<tr><td><input type='text'/></td>" +
        "<td><input type='text' class='num' id='qty" + (i) + "'/></td>" +
        "<td><input type='text' class='num' id='rate" + (i) + "'/></td>" +
        "<td><input type='text' class='num' id='amt" + (i) + "'/></td>");
    newrow.insertAfter('#table1 tbody>tr:last');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<table class="table1" id="table1">
        <thread>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Item Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Qty</th>
      <th scope="col">Rate</th>
      <th scope="col">Amount</th>
    </tr>
  </thread>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="num" name="qty" id="qty" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="num" id="rate" name="rate" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" class="num" id="amt" name="amt" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <a id="add">
        <button>
            Add</button></a>


     <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#add").click(function () {
            var newrow = $('<tr><td><input type="text"></td><td><input type="text" id="qty" name="qty" class="num"></td><td><input type="text" id="rate" name="rate" class="num"></td><td><input type="text" id="amt" name="amt" class="num"></td></tr>');
            newrow.insertAfter('#table1 tbody>tr:last');


            $('#table1 tbody>tr:last').find('[name="qty"]').keyup(function () {
                var this_tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                ;
                var i = parseFloat(this_tr.find('[name="rate"]').val())
                if (!isNaN(i)) {
                    var t = ($(this).val() * this_tr.find('[name="rate"]').val());
                    this_tr.find('[name="amt"]').val(t.toFixed(2));
                } else {
                    this_tr.find('[name="amt"]').val('');
                }
            });
            $('#table1 tbody>tr:last').find('[name="rate"]').keyup(function () {
                var this_tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                ;
                var i = parseFloat(this_tr.find('[name="qty"]').val())
                if (!isNaN(i)) {
                    var t = ($(this).val() * this_tr.find('[name="qty"]').val());
                    this_tr.find('[name="amt"]').val(t.toFixed(2));
                } else {
                    this_tr.find('[name="amt"]').val('');
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
        $('[name="qty"]').keyup(function () {
            var this_tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            ;
            var i = parseFloat(this_tr.find('[name="rate"]').val())
            if (!isNaN(i)) {
                var t = ($(this).val() * this_tr.find('[name="rate"]').val());
                this_tr.find('[name="amt"]').val(t.toFixed(2));
            } else {
                this_tr.find('[name="amt"]').val('');
            }
        });
        $('[name="rate"]').keyup(function () {
            var this_tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            ;
            var i = parseFloat(this_tr.find('[name="qty"]').val())
            if (!isNaN(i)) {
                var t = ($(this).val() * this_tr.find('[name="qty"]').val());
                this_tr.find('[name="amt"]').val(t.toFixed(2));
            } else {
                this_tr.find('[name="amt"]').val('');
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```